# iText libraries to leverage for Form PDF's that are accessible

Tags: tags, itext, accessibility

my problem is that we have a current PDF file that is fillable.  We are leveraging JAVA code along with iText to fill out the PDF template.  Now when saving the final form, all the 'meta data' does not get saved (Tags, Form title, etc).  Are there any specific calls that we need to make to get the final product to be "Accessible" (triple A compliant) when the original form already is.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're using a mighty old version of iText because we've invested in support for PDF/UA in the context of forms a long time ago. We signed up many airlines as a customer when US regulations made PDF/UA a requirement back in 2014 (made mandatory in 2016) Which version are you using? And more importantly: are you a paying customer?

Comment: Could you post your code that you're using? Have you seen this sample? https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/archiving-and-accessibility/clone-creating-simple-pdfua-document This sample shows you how to make a PDF/UA document, which does have several requirements that you might have missed.